# Unable to make Ajax Call - ASP.Net

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, web-services

Using jQuery 1.11.0.
When I make the Ajax call, the error is

> POST http://localhost:9909/Admin/ReportsService.asmx?GetQuestionSets
>   500 (Internal Server Error)

But I am able to browse the URL and run the method without any issue.

**reports.js:**

```
function getQuestionSets() {    
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Admin/ReportsService.asmx?GetQuestionSets",        
        data: "{ 'startDate': '" + $(".txtFromDate").val() + "', 'endDate': '" + $(".txtToDate").val() + "'}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",        
        success: function (msg) {
            console.log(msg.d);
        },
        Error: function (x, e) {
            // On Error
        }
    });
}
```

**ReportsService.asmx:**

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)] 
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class ReportsService : WebService 
{
 [WebMethod]
    public void GetQuestionSets(string startDate, string endDate)
    {
      //code to get data.
    }
}
```

**web.config:**

```
<webServices>
        <protocols>
          <add name="HttpGet" />
          <add name="HttpPost" />
        </protocols>
      </webServices>
    </system.web>
```

The breakpoint for the method `GetQuestionSets` is never hit. 
What am i missing here.

Answer (score 1):

Problem seems to be in the `url` you are calling your method as if you are passing a *querystring*.

Change:

```
 url: "/Admin/ReportsService.asmx?GetQuestionSets"
```

to:

```
 url: "/Admin/ReportsService.asmx/GetQuestionSets"
```

Comment: Issue remains even when changed

Comment: @Qwerty - Make sure you are hitting correct url relative to your JS. I tried your code and its working fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if the data posted to the endpoint is properly formatted. You mention: "I am able to browse the URL and run the method without any issue" -- is that with the actual data logged to the browser console, or by adding the dates by hand? See if the actual logged data (or what you're seeing if you make the call via [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler)) causes an issue.